# Thread safe coroutines with asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio, coroutine

Is there any way I can have thread-safe coroutines along with boost::asio?

I want one `io_service` to be running on multiple threads  and to have some of my handlers be coroutines.

[Boost.Coroutine](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/soc/coroutine/) would seem to be a solution, but they [document](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/soc/coroutine/coroutine/coroutine_thread.html) that they do not support resuming a coroutine that was started in a separate thread.

As far as I know there are only two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Don't use coroutines. Use the much more verbose(even with lambda), but equally functional method of chaining callbacks that store state.
2. Force each handler to only run in one thread. I know this is possible by simply having a separate io_service for each thread. As an aside, is there an easy way, similar to io_service::strand, to force a set of handlers to run in the same thread?

Neither are in any way good solutions. In one solution I lose coroutines. In the other I lose most of my multithreading ability.

Comment: FYI: Have you seen http://blog.think-async.com/2009/08/secret-sauce-revealed.html and http://blog.think-async.com/2010/03/potted-guide-to-stackless-coroutines.html ?

Comment: @Ralf Yeah I have seen that, which is why I am asking this question. Seems like a very cool idea, and an easier way to write asynchronous code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this problem has no easy solution.

The main problem is probably due to the fact that C++ allows compilers to reorder most of what happens in a function. Thus you cannot reliably depend on the order of things happening in functions.

It looks like I am going to have to end up using a series of callbacks, possibly using lambda's if I have a desire to keep everything looking semantically like a block of code.

Perhaps I can even hack something up using macros that resolves to lambdas to simulate the coroutine style.

Comment: FYI, callbacks are an excellent driver for the coroutines if there is a coroutines library that runs the rest of a coroutine from inside the callback (https://code.google.com/p/libglim/source/browse/trunk/test_cbcoro.cc).